Celery and Redis: Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': Unable to load celery application. Module 'project' has no attribute 'celery' [closed]
текст курсивомЗдраствуйте я пытаюсь подключить подключить асинхронные задачи через 'Celery' и брокер сообщений 'Redis'. Установил pip install celery создал файл celery.py рядом с settings.py и в нём прописал следующую конфигурацию


import os from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
app = Celery('project') app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings',
namespace='CELERY') app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.autodiscover_tasks(['accounts', 'shop'])


Также, согласно рекомендациям из документации к Celery, добавил


from .celery import app as celery_app all = ('celery_app',)


Cоздал файл celery.py рядом с settings.py и в нём прописал следующую конфигурацию enter image description here


import os from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
app = Celery('project') app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings',
namespace='CELERY') app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.autodiscover_tasks(['accounts', 'shop'])


Также, согласно рекомендациям из документации к Celery, добавил


from .celery import app as celery_ap
all = ('celery_app',)


C GitHab (https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases) скачал Redis-x64-3.0.504.zip распаковал и открыл файлы 'redis-server.exe' и 'redis-cli.exe'

Установил: pip install redis
и прописал в настройках проекта

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'


Далее в терминале: py manage.py runserver И ввёл: celery -A project worker -l INFO --pool=solo
Но терминал выводит ошибку:

Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]
Try 'celery --help' for help.
Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'project' has no attribute 'celery'


Есть знатоки которые сталкивались с подобным и как исправить ошибку?
Перепробовал менять параметры в файлах, но ошибка так и не уходит.
